# styling table cells based on mysql group

Tags: php, css, mysql

We have a hotel booking table with data as following

```
id  room  night        bookingid  timestamp
1    1    2018-05-01   18         2018-04-07 01:34:41
2    1    2018-05-02   18         2018-04-07 01:34:41
3    1    2018-05-05   19         2018-04-07 01:34:40
4    1    2018-05-06   19         2018-04-07 01:34:40
5    2    2018-05-01   20         2018-04-07 01:34:39
6    2    2018-05-02   20         2018-04-07 01:34:39
7    2    2018-05-03   21         2018-04-07 01:34:37
8    2    2018-05-04   21         2018-04-07 01:34:37
```

current php code to block the dates in the table is:

```
 $sql_query="select * from bookings where ('$year-$month-$i' = night) AND (room=$room)";
```

if there is result then td color become red as the bellow image

data is shown with php as a table cells with bookings as the following :

[image: table]

What i want to achieve is to group the bookings to show as the following 
[image: table]

Any idea how to do so ? 
would like to group the bookings to merge the cells then make the half cell red ( checkout and checkin day )

Comment: Any attempts -in css- to achieve that?

Comment: Need to manage to group the bookings together then make the half cell css code